# How do I call a function from a class/controller in another class/controller?

Tags: 8, page-controller

There are two modules "field_collection" and "tasks"

I have a controller called "task" from the custom module "tasks".

I'd like to use a function in this controller (this function from custom module "field_collection"). Function:

```
Drupal\field_collection\Entity\FieldCollectionItem::load()
```

But when I call this function (from custom module "field_collection") directly in the "task" controller (for the custom module "tasks"):

```
<?php

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
namespace Drupal\tasks\Controller;

class task extends ControllerBase {

public function get_collection_field_n ( $field_collection,$the_collection_field)
{   

    $field = Drupal\field_collection\Entity\FieldCollectionItem::load($field_collection)->get($the_collection_field);
    return $field;
}
}

?>
```

I get the error message:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Drupal\\tasks\\Controller\\FieldCollectionItem' not found in /var/www/pxoa_pub/modules/tasks/src/Controller/task.php on line 41, referer:
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Do you understand [dependency injection](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/services-and-dependency-injection/services-and-dependency-injection-in-drupal-8)? In your case, if you want load field collection you can use  $host = $this->entityTypeManager()->getStorage('field_collection'). May be **field_collection** or **field_collection_item**. I don't know what do you want process in method. After set variable $host  you can use method load.

Comment: Welcome the Drupal Answers :) That's just a general php error, not related to Drupal as such - classes are found relative to the current namespace, so if you want to go back to the root use a leading slash e.g. `\Drupal\foo\bar`.

Comment: Oh, yeah! That's why! I have fixed this issue. Thanks for help @Clive.